# How to sort a multidimensional array on PHP where keys are not string labels

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional array:

```
$serviceTimes = Array (
  [0] => Array ( [0] => PM1900 [1] => 7:00pm )
  [1] => Array ( [0] => PM1900 [1] => 7:00pm )
  [2] => Array ( [0] => PM1415 [1] => 2:15pm )
  [3] => Array ( [0] => PM1919 [1] => 7:19pm )
  [6] => Array ( [0] => PM2020 [1] => 8:20pm )
)
```

But I am unable to sort the array on the [0] element. This does not work:

`array_multisort( $serviceTimes[0], SORT_ASC, $serviceTimes );`

nor does this work

`array_multisort( $serviceTimes[][0], SORT_ASC, $serviceTimes );`

Any thoughts?

Ideally and ultimately, this is what I am looking to produce:

```
Array (
  [0] => 2:15pm )
  [1] => 7:00pm )
  [2] => 7:00pm )
  [3] => 7:19pm )
  [4] => 8:20pm )
)
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php). I bet the answer is already there as an example.

Comment: Amended my OQ @axiac

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 4):

Use `array_column` to extract the `0` column from the sub-arrays and sort on that:

```
array_multisort(array_column($serviceTimes, 0), SORT_ASC, $serviceTimes);
```

You state sorting on the `0` element but your output shows times from the `1` element.  If so just change the `array_column` argument to a `1`.

Comment: Awesome...that's the answer @AbraCadaver. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you may also use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)() with you own compoare function for this kind of custom sort (all functions prefixed with "u" : [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php), [uksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php)...)

```
<?php
function mysort ($a, $b){
    return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
}

$serviceTimes = array ( 0 => array ( 0 => 'PM1900', 1 => '7:00pm', ), 1 => array ( 0 => 'PM1900', 1 => '7:00pm', ), 2 => array ( 0 => 'PM1415', 1 => '2:15pm', ), 3 => array ( 0 => 'PM1919', 1 => '7:19pm', ), 4 => array ( 0 => 'PM2020', 1 => '8:20pm', ), );

usort($serviceTimes, 'mysort');

var_dump(serviceTimes);
```